# Express: share logic between router.post and router.get

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have a form on client-side which is sending data to server through AJAX in my Express app. I want to show some responses to the user when there are errors or the message sent successfully.

This code represents an error message when the message cannot be sent. The specific div in my handlebars template looks like this:

```
<div class="form-validation-error" style="{{formValidationError}}">ERROR: Message cannot be sent!</div>
```

Which is turned off by CSS default:

```
.form-validation-error {
  display: none;
}
```

In my `routes/contact.js` I have a `router.post` block which is handling the message sending:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body.firstname.length === 0 || !req.body.firstname.match(/\D+/igm)) {
    var validateFirstname = false;
  } else {
    var validateFirstname = true;
  };

  if(req.body.captcha.length === 0 || !req.body.captcha.match(/^kettő|ketto|two$/igm)) {
    var validateCaptcha = false;
  } else {
    var validateCaptcha = true;
  };

  if(validateFirstname === true && validateCaptcha === true) {
    console.log('SUCCESS: Form validated! The Nodemailer script will be here!');
  } else {
    console.log('ERROR: Form not validated!');
    const formValidationErrorTrue = 'display: block;'; // -> How can I achieve this!??
    res.send({formValidationError: 'display: block;'}); // -> Or this!??
  };
});
```

After this block, I have a `router.get` template rendering part:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  fsAsync((err, data) => {
    if(err) {
      res.render('404', {
        title: 'Error 404'
      });
    }

    const contact = data[2].contact;

    res.render('contact', {
      title: 'Contact',
      data: contact,
      formValidationError: formValidationErrorTrue // -> How can I achieve this!??
    });
  });
});
```

My question is, how can I share variables between `router.post` and `router.get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method and call that one in both get and post routes. I would encapsulate all logic in a controller instead of directly in your route. Perhaps you could also solve this using middleware (google express middleware) but I usually see that being used for authentication or error logging.

(Sorry for the short answer. I am typing on my phone)

Comment: Thank You the idea. I think I will write a Middleware function in a `router.use`.